# .equals() or == when comparing the class of an object

Tags: java, conditional-statements, equals

In Java, when you are testing what the object's class is equal to would you use `.equals()` or `==`

For example in the code below would it be:

```
if(object.getClass() == MyClass.class)
```

or

```
if(object.getClass().equals(MyClass.class))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java == vs equals() confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: This is a specific version of that. No response in that question, references how to compare classes

Comment: @SleimanJneidi - Read carefully, Tim is asking for comparison of "Class" in his question, not for objects (instances) here, so his question is kind of different from your duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` for that kind of comparison too. The `Class` implementation doesn't override `equals` so comparing using `==` is correct i.e. it will check the runtime class. For example, this code will shows true:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Object object = "";
    
    if (object.getClass() == String.class) {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

The general rule for comparing objects is use 'equals', but for comparing classes if you don´t want to use `instanceof`, i think the correct way is to use `==`.

Comment: `instanceof` is only the same if it's a `final` class.

Answer (score 1):

I personally tend to use the `==` for classes as I think it is slightly more performant. However you have to be aware, that this returns only true if the reference to the object is the same and not only the content (like with `equals`).

For example comparison of two `Class` instances with `==` will return false, if the two instances where loaded by different ClassLoaders.

To be on the save side, you should probably use `equals`

Comment: == is the same as .equals for instances of Class, so there is no point in using .equals.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I suggest you to read the J.Bloch's book *Effective Java*.
As a common rule, you should always tend to use `.equals()` method of a class unless you want to explicitly compare the **pointers** of given instances. That is, you want to compare what the class **represents**, like class of an instance in your examples, or, for example, content of a string but not the pointer to a `String` object.